# Prove ceiling function is lower semicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, ceiling-and-floor-functions, semicontinuous-functions

Can someone give me a hand with this exercise please? I want to prove that the ceiling function is lower semicontinuous, but I am not sure how to do it. It comes in my book as an example, right after the definition, without a proof, so I guess it is very easy. I understand why it is so intuitively but when I try to apply the definition I can't find the delta.

Just for the record, my definition of l.s.c:

> $f: X\to\mathbb R$ is lower semicontinuous on $X$ if for all $c< f(x)$ there exists $d>0$ such that $c< f(y)$ whenever $\|x,y\|< d$

And the ceiling function is the function such that $f(t)=n$ if $n-1< t<= n$

Comment: Where's the exercise?

Comment: Real Analysis by Kolmogorov and Fomin

Comment: No, I mean write down the exercise. You didn't really ask a question yet. You just said "this exercise", but nobody (except you) knows what **this** is supposed to be.

Comment: I want to show that the ceiling function is lsc

Comment: Then **write that into the question**! Don't leave half your question in the comments. The question itself must be self contained. You can edit your question to add the neccesary details.

Comment: Also, your definition is lacking a "for all $x$" in front, but that's not too bad.

Comment: Ok, better now?

Answer (score 1):

You start by going through the definition.

First, the definition says "**for all** $x$ and $c$ such that $c<f(x)$", which means that your proof **must** start with

> Let $x,c$ be such that $c<f(x)$

Which in your case will be

> Let $x,c$ be such that $c<\lceil x \rceil$.

---

Now the next part of the definition says "there **exists** such a $d$..." which means you have to do some work. And that also means I will, at first, only provide hints because they are more useful than full results.

Specifically, you need to find such a $d$ that will force $f(y)$ (in your case, $\lceil y\rceil$) to also be greater than $c$.

You do that by thinking about $x,y$ and $f$.

- Think about what the value of $f(x)$ is.
- Now think about the value of $f(y)$ when $y$ is near $x$. For example, if $x=\frac12$, what is the value of $f(y)$ if $|x-y|<\frac14$?
- What about if $x=1.0001$? What do you have to set $d$ to in order to get the same behaviour as above?

Comment: I think it is d=c/2?

Comment: @Annit Really? What about if $x=927823$ and $c=927822$? **Hint**: if $x=1.0001$, then $d$ must be smaller than $0.0001$ if you want $f$ to be constant. This is the same even if $x=10.0001$ or $x=100.0001$...

Comment: Delta has to be the fractionary part of x, but that is not constant

Comment: @Annit There is no "constant" here. You have to make sure that if **I** pick some $x$ and some $c$, **you** can then (with $x$ and $c$ ***fixed***) produce for me a value of $d$ that will fit the bill. So you can easily say, for example, $d=\frac{[x]}{2}$ (if you can prove that it is the correct choice).

Comment: Ok! I thought delta had to depend only on c

Comment: @Annit Well, the definition you wrote doesn't mention $x$, but in that case, implicitly it means that $\forall x$ stands in front of the whole thing, so yes, you can fix $x$ from the beginning. Otherwise, a proof would not be possible.